# How to set button Action Nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am new in objective-c , i am working on ipad application in which i want to nil a button action. i want action to be performed only one time and after performing action button's action should be nil. I am writing code on button Action:

```
#pragma mark AddCollectors Button Action here

-(void)addCollectors:(id)sender {
    [addCollectors actionsForTarget:nil forControlEvent:UIControlStateNormal];
    myTableView.hidden = YES;
    myTableViewForAddCollectors.hidden = NO;
    [self addTableViewForAddCollectors];
    addCollectors = nil;
}
```

means after adding the tableview button action should be nil.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this method

```
- (void)removeTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

from the documentation:

> Removes a target and action for a particular event (or events) from an
>   internal dispatch table.